# DocumentDB call stored procedure from another stored procedure or itself

Tags: stored-procedures, recursion, azure-cosmosdb

Is there a way to recursively call stored procedures (or even UDFs if that will work) against DocumentDB documents?

We have a document that looks something like this:

```
{
  "docID" : "my_id",
  "owner" : "fred",
  "items" : [
    {
      "itemID" : "1",
      "type" : "item",
      "value" : 3
    },
    {
      "itemID" : "2",
      "type" : "group",
      "items" : [
        {
          "itemID" : "2.1",
          "type" : "group",
          "items" : [
            {
              "itemID" : "2.1.1",
              "type" : "item",
              "value" : 2
            },
            {
              "itemID" : "2.1.2",
              "type" : "item",
              "value" : 4
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "itemID" : "2.2",
          "type" : "item",
          "value" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Any time we have `"items"`, that `"items"` array can contain entries that are a mix of `"type" : "item"` and `"type" : "group"`. Entries that are of `"type" : "item"` have a simple `"value"` field that needs to be summed. Entries that are of `"type" : "group"` have an `"items"` array... and so on. In theory, there is no limit to the level of recursion, which I acknowledge is a problem, but in practice, the levels will rarely get below 4 or 5 deep.

Pseudocode for what I'm trying to write looks something like this:

```
function sumValues(items) {
    int total = 0;
    forEach(item in items) {
        if (item.type == "item") {
            total += item.value;
        } else {
            total += sumValues(item.items);
        }
    }
    return total;
}

function sumAllValues() {
  var ctx = getContext();
  var coll = ctx.getCollection();
  var response = ctx.getResponse();

  // query for docs by owner
  var filterQuery = 'SELECT * FROM Docs d where d.owner = \\\"fred\\\"';
  var done = coll.queryDocuments(coll.getSelfLink(), filterQuery, {},
    function (err, docs, options) {
      if (err) throw new Error ('Error' + err.message);

      var total = 0;
      docs.forEach(function(doc) {
        total += sumTotals(doc.items);
      });

      response.setBody('Total: ' + total);
    });
}
```

Is this even possible? Does DocumentDB support calling a sproc from another sproc? Can a sproc call itself?

I have found a few DocumentDB stored procedure references online, including [this](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-programming/) and [this](http://janatdevelopment.com/2014/10/05/cool-nosql-on-azure-with-documentdb/) and [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/documentdb-interactions-with-resources.md) and [this](http://dl.windowsazure.com/documentDB/jsserverdocs/) plus a host of other pages.

If it's possible, I think I might have to somehow query the collection to get the sproc that I want to call, and then somehow reference the sproc, instead of just calling `sumTotals()` directly as you would with a standalone language.

We're just starting to look at programming with DocumentDB, so we're not completely sure what we can do with it yet. Thanks for any assistance or advice.

Comment: I might be able to use something out of [this](http://www.documentdb.com/javascript/tutorial#transactions) example that defines a function `swapItems` that is called directly from the parent function.

Comment: Vote
[here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/16267270-allow-to-use-udf-user-defined-function-inside-a-d) to add this option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're on the right track here.

It is not possible to execute a stored procedure from within a stored procedure.

However, you **can** define JS functions inside a stored procedure, which can be can be referenced, called, and re-used from within that stored procedure.

In this case, simply define your `sumValues()` function inside the parent `sumAllValues()` stored procedure (just like the `swapItems()` example you mentioned).

```
function sumAllValues() {
    var ctx = getContext();
    var coll = ctx.getCollection();
    var response = ctx.getResponse();

    // query for docs by owner
    var filterQuery = 'SELECT * FROM Docs d where d.owner = \\\"fred\\\"';
    var done = coll.queryDocuments(coll.getSelfLink(), filterQuery, {},
        function (err, docs, options) {
            if (err) throw new Error ('Error' + err.message);

            var total = 0;
            docs.forEach(function(doc) {
                total += sumValues(doc.items);
            });

            response.setBody('Total: ' + total);
        });

    function sumValues(items) {
        int total = 0;
        items.forEach(function(item) {
            if (item.type == "item") {
                total += item.value;
            } else {
                total += sumValues(item.items);
            }
        });
        return total;
    }
}
```

You can also define UDFs for logic you'd like to share and re-use across multiple stored procedures and queries.

Comment: That suggestion -- moving the sumValues function definition inside the sproc definition -- worked for me, so I've updated your answer with the code example and will accept it.